# event.target.form returns null in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs, internet-explorer, events

I am building a complete dynamic rendering web application using ReactJS. In a case, I need to get the form elements on click action.

So, I used `event.target.form.elements` and it worked well in Chrome and Mozilla. But when I test the Application in IE, returns null. ie `event.target.form` is null.

From blog suggestions, I used `event.currentTarget` and `event ? event.target : window.event.srcElement` but that too didn't work. I wrote a function doing similar as below,

```
function getTarget(e) {
  var evn = e || window.event;
  return evn.srcElement || e.target;
}
```

still didn't work.

Is there any work around to get this get passed in IE browser. The version on IE using is IE 11.

Comment: the error is saying event is undefined or there is no form element in the target. in my knowledge there is no **form** attribut one html node by default. would you say forms ??

Comment: It is 'form' only. Couldn't attach the screenshot of the issue. The error retuned is **'Unable to get property 'elements' of undefined or null reference' ** . As stated above, the code used is 'event.target.form.elements' whereas form is null.

Comment: when using react event.target / event.currentTarget is weird. can you show the code where you call the getTarget function?

Comment: `function doMapping(){
   inputSections[i].AnswerElements = 
                          getTarget(event).form.elements[currentQName];
   inputSections[i].Answer = 
                          bindAnswerValuesToJson(inputSections[i], 
                        inputSections[i].AnswerElements, 
                           getTarget(event).form.elements);`
  }
  
  `function getTarget(e) {
    var evn = e || window.event;
    return evn.srcElement || e.target;
  }`

Comment: If event.target / event.currentTarget  is not good to use, can you suggest what other will do similar operation ?